# Change parameters on go_form in oracle forms 6

Tags: forms, oracle, parameters, reset

The question is rather simple. Let's I have say two forms: A and B. B uses some parameters to query a data block.
Let's say you can initialise these parameters in form A, and when you navigate to form B through A, A will pass those parameters to B, and B will query the block in when-window-activated.

Now, let's say I go back to form A, without closing B. I select another record on A, and I want to navigate again to B, but with different parameters (the new ones I selected). I don't want to open another instance of B, so I use go_form('B').

But the new parameters won't be loaded in B, so B will requery the first set of parameters, instead of the second set of parameters.

So I wondered if there is a way to reset/change parameters in form B, preferably while using go_form('B').

It would really help me out!

Comment: Possible solution [from Oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/902631?start=0&tstart=0): "You can put your "context" value into a global, and then use GO_FORM to navigate to the second form and in that form use the WHEN-WINDOW-ACTIVATED-trigger to check the global and requery data."

Comment: Well, globals are kinda 'dirty' because they are global for all the forms. If two navigation globals have the same name, things can get messy when more than one user is using the program. I am working with globals at this moment, but I wanted to know if there is a more clean solution for this problem. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close the form B before reopening it with close_form('formname') command.